# Change ShareThis title on button click

Tags: jquery, share, sharethis

I'm loading sharethis buttons into fancybox on button click using span tags:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div class="social-share">
        <span class='st_facebook_vcount' displayText='Facebook'></span>
        <span class='st_twitter_vcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>
        <span class='st_pinterest_vcount' displayText='Pinterest'></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is:

How can I change st_title or set the title for the shared content based on what button I click. For example, my page has basically one share button for each post, so if I would think of making a button like this:

```
 <a class="share-btn" href="#" data-title="First Post">Share This</a>
```

And then attempt to do something here:

```
 $('a.share-btn').on('click', function(e){
      //Change shared title

      //launch fancybox containing share <span>'s mentioned above
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set the title via data() setter method.

```
$('a.share-btn').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var titletext='some title';
      $(this).data('title',titletext);
 }
```